# Using numbers as assoc array keys

Tags: php, arrays

It seems to work, but it feels wrong, I assume it is.

Is it wrong?

If so, I currently have an array with keys being mysql database id's and the values being their values.

Would it be better to have the key being `"record_"+$id` and then `explode()`ing the key and getting the `id` from that?

Or is it ok to set your own array keys, and php will just assume they are assoc array keys, rather than indexes?

Thanks

Comment: PHP doesn't care what you use for keys. You can mix strings and numbers as much as you want. The only restriction is that you have to use actual values.

Comment: There is no difference between numerical associative array keys and indexes. So long as the associative array key contains only integers and no leading zeros, it will be treated as if it were an integer index key. `print_r(array('1'=>'string1', 1=>'int1'));` output: `Array ( [1] => int1 ) `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some built-in PHP functions (like [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) / [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)) will re-index your array:

> **array_merge()** If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If,
>   however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not
>   overwrite the original value, but will be appended. Values in the
>   input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing
>   keys starting from zero in the result array.

---

> **array_multisort()** can be used to sort several arrays at once, or a multi-dimensional array by one or more dimensions. Associative
>   (string) keys will be maintained, but numeric keys will be re-indexed.

I would advise you not to do that, use a proper value instead, or at the very least prefix it with a short `_`:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $id = ltrim($key, '_');

    // do stuff with the actual $id
}
```

Comment: Cool, thats the answer I was looking for. :) Thank you for your clear explanation.

Comment: Thank you! This was throwing me for a loop, but your response answered my issue as well.